# What does the interface between lead(s) and the silicon chip look like inside a semiconductor package?

Tags: transistors, diodes, semiconductors, thermal, packages

For a leaded semiconductor, like a diode or a transistor, one of the leads is usually the same piece of metal as the copper pad/heat spreader on the back, which is also shorted to one of the junctions (anode, drain, etc.).

My question is how do the remaining leads interface with the silicon chip inside the package?

Comment: Youtube video showing DIY wire bonding of ICs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvZ1dJuvenw

Answer (score 2):

Usually with itty bitty wires that are welded to the chip and the leadframe.

[image: ic leadframe and wires]

Image from Wikipedia: Wire Bonding

Comment: Right, and sometimes a clip package for low inductance/resistance (usually power semiconductors). https://electronics360.globalspec.com/article/11548/the-benefits-of-copper-clip-over-wire-bond-packaging